# What units to pass UI methods?

Tags: android

Reading the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) of the Android developer guide it says it is always best to use density independent pixels (dp) instead of pixels and it also says Android handles most of the application rendering on different density devices.

Now my question is, if we look at the padding function of the View class

> setPadding (int left, int top, int
>   right, int bottom)

```
left     the left padding in pixels
top       the top padding in pixels
right   the right padding in pixels
bottom    the bottom padding in pixels
```

When I use this function is it alright to pass direct values or do I have to pass converted values, from dp to px, to best show the UI in all devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this padding reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and search for android:padding

It looks like you will need to convert from dip to pixels to set the padding.  You should convert the values from dip to pixels so that it works correctly on different devices.

Comment: thanks. I think the same. Actually I had checked only the setPadding function description and missed reading the android:padding description from doc. By it's description it seems we have to convert dp to pixel for setPadding function.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your dip value to pixels and pad with that.

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

int valuePixels = (int)(valueDip * scale);
```